# how to send mail with expiry date, auto delete from inbox

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

this is the method to send mail by python program.

```
def Send_Mail(self, username, password, receiver, subject, body):
    username = str(username)
    password = str(password)
    receiver = str(receiver)
    subject = str(subject)
    body = str(body)
    Username = username
    Password = password
    Sender = username
    Destination = [receiver]
    Subject = subject
    Content = body
    text_subtype = 'html'
    SMTPserver = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    msg = MIMEText(Content, text_subtype)
    msg['Subject'] = Subject
    msg['From'] = Sender
    conn = SMTP(SMTPserver)
    conn.set_debuglevel(False)
    conn.login(Username, Password)
    conn.sendmail(Sender, Destination, msg.as_string())
    conn.close()
```

calling this method by

```
Classname.Send_Mail(<emailid>,<password>,<destination email-id>,<subject>,<body>
```

this code is working perfectly,
but need to set expiry date while sending mail,so that sent mail must auto delete from the inbox after specified time. 
help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what gave you the impression email supports such a feature? I am not aware of any email client supporting 'auto-deletion' of received email..

Comment: I think `E-mails` i e `Gmails` will be expiring after 9 months(i m not sure) automatically,so thought.

Comment: Gmail is just standard internet email with a really nice UI. If Google expires email automatically, that'll be their choice, but it's *not* part of any standard or something you can make happen by setting extra headers.

Comment: Not limiting this idea with only SMTP, other servers like `POP3 server` and `IMAP server`, asking Can it possible with any other server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such things as "auto-delete" anywhere in the SMTP or [another mail related standard](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2076.html#b). Additionally I have never heard of a "feature" like this.

So the answer is: **You can't**

(Maybe their are mail clients that support such things but this would be a "works only in client X" feature. So for an more useful answer you would have to provide the target client.)

Comment: LIke other stated below Expires is part of the the standard. but there is not garantee that Client X supports it.  So the answer is: Yes you can but it is unclear if the recipients client supports it.

Answer (score 6):

`Expiry-Date` was replaced with `Expires` as the SMTP header to indicate the expiration of the usefulness of an email message. See [the relevant section of RFC 4021](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021#section-2.1.50).

That said, although it's standardized, I don't think it's seen widespread adoption and the header is no guarantee that a message will be deleted. Microsoft Outlook does [show an expired message with a strikethrough style](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-your-email-message-cfc102b7-43bf-408b-8a47-f0c09b086d01#__toc257316818), though.

Comment: What's the format of the value to be set to this header?

Answer (score 3):

Set the "Expiry-Date" header in the mail, most clients will acknowlege it (and either expire, flag as deleted, ask for permission, etc)